# Is there an Aperture equivalent for Windows, or do I need to use both Picasa and Lightroom?

Tags: software, lightroom, picasa, windows, apple-aperture

As much as I'd like to work with Aperture, my main machine runs Windows (I only have a Macbook, no desktop Mac). For now, I have been using jointly Picasa and Lightroom for my photo management and editing needs.

*Picasa*, because it watches my photos folder (I have a flat architecture), has an easy interface, it pretty fast, but mainly because it does **face recognition** (I am insanely in love with this feature in general, being able to show all pictures of grandma and aunt Lily in two clicks is awesome) and uses **geotagging** to place my photos on a map.

*Lightroom*, because it allows me to do very **fine tuning** of my pictures, has great **export** functionalities and is more enthusiast-oriented in general.

As far as I know, *Aperture* has all these features that I am looking for in one single program, which would be perfect. Indeed, using Picasa and Lightroom in parallel is a mess, the edits may be lost, and I have to resync Lightroom often.

Do you know if such thing exists for Windows ? Or will I have either to wait for Lightroom to get face recognition and mapping, or to go to Mac ?

Comment: Not sure if you saw this question as well? http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/any-good-alternatives-to-lightroom-for-pc-users

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll have a look. But it seems that there's nothing like what I'm looking for :(...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd concur with the analysis you've done thus far.

Adobe has added people recognition to Photoshop Elements 9; I wouldn't be surprised to see this added to Lightroom in the future.

There is at least one solid [plugin for Lightroom to support geotagging](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/gps) although it's a shadow geotag and not injecting it directly into the "main" GPS fields.

While Aperture has these features, it also is a bit lacking in some areas where Lightroom shines - the editing controls aren't as powerful and it doesn't support smart object integration with Photoshop.

For further thoughts on Picasa/Lightroom, [check out this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/picasa-vs-lightroom-whats-the-difference) if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the plugin. I saw the question about Picasa VS Lightroom, and I actually know quite well what are their differences.